What is best way to track and store changes to entities using .NET and EF Core?
Let's say that we have Movie entity which has properties Id, Title, PublishDate and Description.
If we want to track and store changes of entity for future use what would be best way to do it ? E.g. we want to fetch and group all changes.
Results should be like "Title was changed to RandomTitle" and e.g. date of change.
I understand how to implement auditing with CreatedAt and ModifiedAt but I never faced problem that I should actually store history of changes.
The thing that comes to my mind is to create separate MovieHistory table where I would store all changes.

The best way is to not use the ORM but database features like SQL Server's temporal tables. If a database doesn't have this, triggers can store modified rows in a separate History table. What database are you using?

I will use SQL Server running inside Docker container. I will check the temporal tables. Thank you.

EF Core supports temporal tables. Check EF Core - Temporal tables. The AWS Aurora PostgreSQL docs all places has a nice example showing how temporal tables can be used for anomaly detection just before saying this isn't supported

Questions about best practices are nearly always opinion-based. Unless there's one absolutely unequivocal best practice, such question are not a good fit for for Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this question falls into that category.

Temporal tables can be an option, but may be overkill as they make working with the schema more complex when dealing with relationships. If you want a simple audit change a couple of options are to mark entities you want  to audit with a marker interface (I.e. IAuditable) and detect this on an overridden SaveChanges() then looking over ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified) for entities that are cast-able to the marker interface. From there you can format an audit record for any values that have changed using CurrentValues and OriginalValues.

Might want to look at the event sourcing pattern?  But if not, what I've done on one of my projects that's been working pretty well is extending the DbContext class(es) and inserting some code in the SaveChangesAsync() and other save methods before calling base.SaveChangesAysnc().  I do it to update cached data, but it would work equally well to grab a snapshot of changed data.
Might look something like this:
public partial class Snapshot_MovieContext : MovieContext
{
     public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

      return Task.Run(async () =>
      {
        var entityEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
        entityEntries.ForEach(e => {
         //Do your save stuff here 
        });
        int result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return result;
      });

    }
}

Then inject Snapshot_MovieContext and use it instead of MovieContext in your EF calls.  You'll want to override all of the "Save" methods in DbContext, most likely.
Edit: Whoops, someone else proposed essentially the same thing up above.
